# How to inhibit line breaks when calling echo several times in a row

Tags: shell

I have created an alias for Git:

`alias gtbs='echo on Branch; git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD; echo last Modified; git status -s;'`

but this prints output each on newline

like

```
on Branch:
develop
Added/Modified:
 M scripts/myscript
```

while instead i just want in one line

```
on Branch: develop, Added/Modified: M scripts/myscript
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `echo` command adds an implicit newline, which you're observing.

Either pass the `-n` command-line option to `echo` (but [this is not POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), though many shells implement it, as well as `/bin/echo` from the [`coreutils`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) project, typically found on GNU/Linux systems) or use the [`printf` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/printf.html) like this:

```
printf 'on branch: %s, last modified: %s' \
    $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) $(git status -s)
```

(The `\\` is here for formatting purposes.)

You can also use backticks `` `...` `` instead of `$(...)`.

Also note that `git status` itself might produce output spanning several lines, so I'd say the most sensible thing would be to ask `printf` to insert the newline right before the output of `git status`, so the whole encantation would become:

```
printf 'printf 'on branch: %s, last modified:\n' \
    $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && git-status -s
```

If, for some reason you *do* mean to have `git status -s` output a single line, you might want to delete any newlines from it:

```
printf '...last modified: %s' $(git status -s | paste -sd ,)
```

…and if you want multiple-character separators, the last encantation would become a bit more involved:

```
$(IFS=\n git-status -s | while read line; do printf '%s; ' "$line"; done)
```

Comment: @san, note that you might also add a *Git* alias for this: `git config add --global alias.gtbs '!printf "on branch: %s, last modified: %s" $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) $(git status -s)'`, and it will be callable as `git gtbs`.

Comment: where does this git alias gets saved, i mean in which file?

Comment: @san, there are three levels: system, global and local (per-repository). Do `git help config` for more info.